# RoR Selecting data to show data

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, view

How is the easiest way to make a selectio field which will retrive other information? I have an Ajax script to make this, i think i can make it work. But srsly, i can't figure out how to make in the view or controller actions to let me select a data from the table and get other data related to it.

This is my code, this may help understand what i'm trying to say.

```
<%= form_for(@page) do |f| %>

 <div id="jstree">

  <ul>
  <li> <%= f.collection_select :cliente_id, Cliente.order(:name), :id, :name, prompt: "Selecionar", :required => true %>
    <ul>
      <li id="child_node_1"><%= f.projeto.name %>
    <ul>
      <li id="child_node_2"><%= f.task.descr %></li></li></ul>

       </ul>
     </li>
   </ul>
 </div>
```

Comment: Which column are you trying to select from the database table?

Comment: I have 3 tablets, one for client, one for projects and one for tasks, Tasks has a column which stores the project ID and project  stores client Id.

Comment: Which view/controller is this file?

Comment: pages view , i want to put in a different page, a selector to select a Cliente which will find by id its projects and its tasks..
Like this  def show
@projetos = Projeto.find(:all, :conditions =>  ["projeto.id" == "@task.projeto_id"])
  end

Comment: Is that the show action in PagesController?

Comment: no, it was actually from the Projetos Controller, i dunno if this code is right, just a example of what im trying to do.

Comment: So you will need to find the Projecto in PagesController. The Show function gives you the ID of a page, you must get the Projecto based on this ID. Your Pages model should define the relationship between a Page and a Projecto

Comment: my page has only index(but i understood what u said about show), i had set up relations with has_many and belong to. In the index i need to put a selector where it'll have all Client names and then will do a searching based on client_id in the project table which has a client_id column(client:references) and search again in tasks table based on project_id(project:references).

Comment: You can use find_all_by_id to find Projectos with all client IDs, and then do the same for tasks

Comment: could you please send em an example, i'm really new to rails...